# Is there a way to adress the backgroung color in Google Sheets conditional formating?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am making a Roadmap for a project of mine in Google sheets. I want to set the background color of a row to light red if the row is the current date. I do this with conditional formating. When the row is colored my old background colors are overwritten.
Is there a way to color only cells that have no manual background color?

[The light red row works fine, but the darker red underneath should still be seen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KR4O.png)

[image: The light red row works fine, but the darker red underneath should still be seen.]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to color only cells that have no manual background color?

unfortunately that is not possible. conditional formatting always takes priority over manual colors